# Only XML files to GDrive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I receive emails with attachments in PDF and XML, the code I'm using today records both files in GDrive, I want to send only the XML to GDrive.

```js
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('NFs'); // <-- RENAME TO YOUR CUSTOM FILTER LABEL
var moveToLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('NFs Import'); // <-- Uncomment to move to new label after download
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19vKRsoFwVyXOxvWkE'); //  <-- INSERT GSHEET_ID
var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Email");  //  <-- Enter Sheet-Name where records should be created
var destinationFolderID = '1noxxKIgg4N3G0Ob'; // <-- Enter the ID of the folder to copy files to
var threads = label.getThreads();
threads.forEach(thread => {
  var messages = thread.getMessages();
  messages.forEach(message => {
    var sent = message.getDate();
    var sender = message.getFrom();
    var subject = message.getSubject();
    var attachments = message.getAttachments({
      includeInlineImages: false,
      includeInlineAttachments: false
    });
    var attachmentNames = [];
    attachments.forEach(attachment => {
      Drive.Files.insert({ title: attachment.getName(), mimeType: attachment.getContentType(), parents: [{ id: destinationFolderID }] }, attachment.copyBlob());
      attachmentNames.push([attachment.getName()]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create only XML file from `attachments`.

In this case, how about checking the mimeType or the extension of the filename? When this is reflected in your script, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
attachments.forEach(attachment => {
Drive.Files.insert({ title: attachment.getName(), mimeType: attachment.getContentType(), parents: [{ id: destinationFolderID }] }, attachment.copyBlob());

    
    attachmentNames.push([attachment.getName()]);
    
});
```

#### To:

```
attachments.forEach(attachment => {
  if (attachment.getContentType().toLowerCase().includes("xml") || attachment.getName().toLowerCase().includes(".xml")) {
    Drive.Files.insert({ title: attachment.getName(), mimeType: attachment.getContentType(), parents: [{ id: destinationFolderID }] }, attachment.copyBlob());
    attachmentNames.push([attachment.getName()]);
  }
});
```

or

```
attachments.forEach(attachment => {
  if (attachment.getContentType() != MimeType.PDF) {
    Drive.Files.insert({ title: attachment.getName(), mimeType: attachment.getContentType(), parents: [{ id: destinationFolderID }] }, attachment.copyBlob());
    attachmentNames.push([attachment.getName()]);
  }
});
```

- By this modification, the XML data or the file except for PDF data are created as a file.

#### Note:

- In your showing script, 2 `forEach` are not enclosed. I'm not sure about your actual script. But, please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [getContentType() of Class Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getContentType())
- [getName() of Class Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getName())